# how to display something on page if GET variable not set?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I currently have my page like this, www.page.com/bars.php?monday, www.page.com/bars.php?tuesday, etc. Depending on what day is set, I display different content. Here is how I do it:

```
        if (isset($_GET['monday']) && empty($_GET['monday'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_mon`";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("no query");

            $objects = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $objects[] = $row;
            }

            foreach($objects as $object) {

                echo
                '<div class="bars-loc-cont">
                    <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><img src="' . $object['img_link'] . '" /></a>
                    <div class="bars-info">
                        <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><p class="bars-title">' . $object['title'] . '</p></a>
                        <p class="bars-line-1">' . $object['line_1'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-2">' . $object['line_2'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-3">' . $object['line_3'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-4">' . $object['line_4'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-5">' . $object['line_5'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';

            }
        } else if (isset($_GET['tuesday']) && empty($_GET['tuesday'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_tues`";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("no query");

            $objects = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $objects[] = $row;
            }

            foreach($objects as $object) {

                echo
                '<div class="bars-loc-cont">
                    <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><img src="' . $object['img_link'] . '" /></a>
                    <div class="bars-info">
                        <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><p class="bars-title">' . $object['title'] . '</p></a>
                        <p class="bars-line-1">' . $object['line_1'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-2">' . $object['line_2'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-3">' . $object['line_3'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-4">' . $object['line_4'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-5">' . $object['line_5'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';

            }
        } else if (isset($_GET['wednesday']) && empty($_GET['wednesday'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_wed`";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("no query");

            $objects = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $objects[] = $row;
            }

            foreach($objects as $object) {

                echo
                '<div class="bars-loc-cont">
                    <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><img src="' . $object['img_link'] . '" /></a>
                    <div class="bars-info">
                        <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><p class="bars-title">' . $object['title'] . '</p></a>
                        <p class="bars-line-1">' . $object['line_1'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-2">' . $object['line_2'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-3">' . $object['line_3'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-4">' . $object['line_4'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-5">' . $object['line_5'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';

            }
        } else if (isset($_GET['thursday']) && empty($_GET['thursday'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_thurs`";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("no query");

            $objects = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $objects[] = $row;
            }

            foreach($objects as $object) {

                echo
                '<div class="bars-loc-cont">
                    <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><img src="' . $object['img_link'] . '" /></a>
                    <div class="bars-info">
                        <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><p class="bars-title">' . $object['title'] . '</p></a>
                        <p class="bars-line-1">' . $object['line_1'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-2">' . $object['line_2'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-3">' . $object['line_3'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-4">' . $object['line_4'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-5">' . $object['line_5'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';

            }
        } else if (isset($_GET['friday']) && empty($_GET['friday'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_fri`";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("no query");

            $objects = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $objects[] = $row;
            }

            foreach($objects as $object) {

                echo
                '<div class="bars-loc-cont">
                    <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><img src="' . $object['img_link'] . '" /></a>
                    <div class="bars-info">
                        <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><p class="bars-title">' . $object['title'] . '</p></a>
                        <p class="bars-line-1">' . $object['line_1'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-2">' . $object['line_2'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-3">' . $object['line_3'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-4">' . $object['line_4'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-5">' . $object['line_5'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';

            }
        } else if (isset($_GET['saturday']) && empty($_GET['saturday'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_sat`";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("no query");

            $objects = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $objects[] = $row;
            }

            foreach($objects as $object) {

                echo
                '<div class="bars-loc-cont">
                    <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><img src="' . $object['img_link'] . '" /></a>
                    <div class="bars-info">
                        <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><p class="bars-title">' . $object['title'] . '</p></a>
                        <p class="bars-line-1">' . $object['line_1'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-2">' . $object['line_2'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-3">' . $object['line_3'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-4">' . $object['line_4'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-5">' . $object['line_5'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';

            }
        } else if (isset($_GET['sunday']) && empty($_GET['sunday'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_sun`";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("no query");

            $objects = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $objects[] = $row;
            }

            foreach($objects as $object) {

                echo
                '<div class="bars-loc-cont">
                    <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><img src="' . $object['img_link'] . '" /></a>
                    <div class="bars-info">
                        <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><p class="bars-title">' . $object['title'] . '</p></a>
                        <p class="bars-line-1">' . $object['line_1'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-2">' . $object['line_2'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-3">' . $object['line_3'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-4">' . $object['line_4'] . '</p>
                        <p class="bars-line-5">' . $object['line_5'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';

            }
        }
```

What I want to know is, when the user goes to www.page.com/bars.php only, how can I make so that I show something like if it were one of the days? And if i select a day, I would like to hide the bars.php content and display only the bars.php?'day' contents. Also, is there any way to make this code shorter? seems like there would be a much shorter way of doing this.

Comment: Just write everything in your else condition after if condition for sunday.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer I tried that, but when I go to www.page.com/bars.php, nothing but the site template shows. no content from database.

Comment: i think there should be `!empty` condition to be checked

Comment: If user goes to www.page.com/bars.php only,  you can identify what day it is actually that day for e.g. today is a Thursday. Assign a php variable to `strtolower(date(l))` and it will give you current day in lowercase and then you can proceed with your logic.

Comment: Why isn't there any code to handle the cases where `$_GET['xxxday']` is set but **not** empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url should be www.page.com/bars.php?day=tuesday

```
<?php
    $day = (isset($_GET['day']) && !empty($_GET['day']))?$_GET['day']:'';
    switch ($day) {
        case "monday":
             $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_mon`";
            break;
        case "tuesday":
             $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_tues`";
            break;
        case "wednesday":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_wed`";
            break;
        case "thursday":
             $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_thurs`";
            break;
        case "friday":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_fri`";
            break;
        case "saturday":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_sat`";
            break;
        case "sunday":
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_sun`";
            break;
        default:
            $query = false;
    }
    if($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("no query");
        $objects = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $objects[] = $row;
        }

        foreach($objects as $object) {
            echo
            '<div class="bars-loc-cont">
                <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><img src="' . $object['img_link'] . '" /></a>
                <div class="bars-info">
                    <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><p class="bars-title">' . $object['title'] . '</p></a>
                    <p class="bars-line-1">' . $object['line_1'] . '</p>
                    <p class="bars-line-2">' . $object['line_2'] . '</p>
                    <p class="bars-line-3">' . $object['line_3'] . '</p>
                    <p class="bars-line-4">' . $object['line_4'] . '</p>
                    <p class="bars-line-5">' . $object['line_5'] . '</p>
                </div>
            </div>';

        }
    } else {
        echo 'your other code here';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: So my days links would have to lead  to: www.page.com/bars.php?day=monday instead of just www.page.com/bars.php?monday  ?

Comment: I seem to be getting no query for all days of the week even when my address page shows www.page.com/bars.php?day=monday

Comment: please check the $_GET variable what value set in day variable.

Comment: got it working, just had a typo, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get keys from `$_GET` using array_keys.

You will get day as first value.

**Steps:**

1) Check if `$_GET` is not empty.

2) Get keys of the array with array_keys.

3) Create an array of allowed week days.

4) Create another multidimensional array of days and database tables.

5) Where key is day and value is database table name.

6) If everything is fine, get name of database table using the `day` key.

7) This will be database table name.

8) If it is not empty, do the rest of work.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$days = isset($_GET) && ! empty($_GET) ? array_keys($_GET) : array();
$day = (current($days)) ? strtolower(current($days)) : '';
$allowedDays = array('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'); // Only allowed days.
if (! in_array($day, $allowedDays)) {
  die('incorrect day');
}
$dbTables = array();
$dbTables['monday'] = 'bars_mon';
$dbTables['tuesday'] = 'bars_tues';
$dbTables['wednesday'] = 'bars_wed';
$dbTables['thursday'] = 'bars_thurs';
$dbTables['friday'] = 'bars_fri';
$dbTables['saturday'] = 'bars_sat';
$dbTables['sunday'] = 'bars_sun';
$tableName = isset($dbTables[$day]) ? $dbTables[$day] : '';
if (! empty($tableName)) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `" . $tableName . "`";
  // REST OF THE CODE...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler approach, that allows for a default:

calling with `?day=mon`, for example

```
$days = array(
    "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun",
);

$day = "mon";
if (isset($_GET['day']) && in_array($_GET['day'], $days)) {
    $day = $_GET['day'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `bars_$day`";

$result = mysqli_query($query) or die("no query");

$objects = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $objects[] = $row;
}

foreach($objects as $object) {
    echo
    '<div class="bars-loc-cont">
        <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><img src="' . $object['img_link'] . '" /></a>
        <div class="bars-info">
            <a href="' . $object['link'] . '"><p class="bars-title">' . $object['title'] . '</p></a>
            <p class="bars-line-1">' . $object['line_1'] . '</p>
            <p class="bars-line-2">' . $object['line_2'] . '</p>
            <p class="bars-line-3">' . $object['line_3'] . '</p>
            <p class="bars-line-4">' . $object['line_4'] . '</p>
            <p class="bars-line-5">' . $object['line_5'] . '</p>
        </div>
    </div>';

}
```

A few tips for future:

- Seriously, stop using mysql_* functions - they're deprecated and unsafe. mysqli_* is better, but look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements.
- Look into better error handling than calling `die()` - you want nice error messages for users and not raw text
- Look into separating data logic (models) from presentation (views)
- When each branch in an if/else chain uses the same 15 lines of code and only varies by one value, look at rewriting your code. Now, if you add new information to your output, you only have to update your code once and not seven times.

Comment: this is a great answer, helps me out a lot!! Only thing is, I would like my default page to be bars.php since the only way to get to this page is a link that takes you to bars.php. Only when you are in bars.php, can you select mon, tue, wed, thu, etc. I would like my bars.php page to have the same content as my days pages, but it would be pulling data from another table

Comment: not sure I quite understand about "another table" - but with this code, if you call bars.php without the day parameter, you will get the Monday day

Comment: So I have a database with 8 tables, bars_mon, bars_tues, bars_wed, bars_thurs, bars_fri, bars_sat, bars_sun. And I also have another table that is just called bars. I want the data in that table to be loaded when the address bar shows www.page.com/bars.php without any days.

Comment: Ah, I see. Better to have all bars in one table and have a day column. If you have no day, select all. If you have a day, use a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass monday or any other day like:

```
www.page.com/bars.php?day=monday

then

you can access like:  $_GET['day']
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the page, check if your `$GET` is empty

```
if (empty($_GET)) {
  // no data passed by get, Set your get to your current day or any other day
    $current_day = date('l');
    $_GET[$current_day] = /**set it to what you want*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go with this:

```
<?php

# Check if weekday is passed in GET paramater in index `on`
# if not set then get current weekday using PHP date function
# to show current day records instead showing empty page
$day = (isset($_GET['on']) && !empty($_GET['on'])) ? $_GET['on'] : strtolower(date('l'));

$weekdays_and_db_tables = array(
    'sunday' => 'sun',
    'monday' => 'mon',
    'tuesday' => 'tues',
    'wednesday' => 'wed',
    'thursday' => 'thurs',
    'friday' => 'fri',
    'saturday' => 'sat',
);

# Now check if weekdays is correct
if (!isset($weekdays_and_db_tables[$day]) or $weekdays_and_db_tables[$day] == '') {
    die('Invalid weekday!');
}

# SQL Injection can cause here, so beware
# you should migrate all table in one and filter records using an extra column `weekday`
$query = printf("SELECT * FROM `bars_%s`", $weekdays_and_db_tables[$day]);
# instead separate table for each weekdays migrate in one and do:
$query_x = printf("SELECT * FROM `bars_weekdays` WHERE `weekday` = '%s'", $weekdays_and_db_tables[$day]);
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die("no query");

while($object = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div class="bars-loc-cont">
    <a href="{$object['link']}"><img src="{$object['img_link']}" /></a>
    <div class="bars-info">
        <a href="{$object['link']}"><p class="bars-title">{$object['title']}</p></a>
        <p class="bars-line-1">{$object['line_1']}</p>
        <p class="bars-line-2">{$object['line_2']}</p>
        <p class="bars-line-3">{$object['line_3']}</p>
        <p class="bars-line-4">{$object['line_4']}</p>
        <p class="bars-line-5">{$object['line_5']}</p>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;
}
```

Comment: I've used `mysqli_*` instead `mysql_*`. MySQLi is more secured. So, go with this.